# For VS Code what is the accepted alternative to the deprecated TextEditor.hide() function?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How does one close an editor programmatically in Visual Studio Code? The docs say `TextEditor.hide()` is deprecated and that we should "Use the command `workbench.action.closeActiveEditor` instead", but I can't find the `workbench.action` API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really an "API", but an identifier for a command in the command palette (see `keybindings.json` for a list). An extension can invoke commands via `executeCommand()`:

```typescript
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");
```

This is equivalent to selecting the `View: Close Editor` command manually or pressing the associated shortcut:

[image]